# How to use JavaMail Api in Android

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

I have an Html to send as an email from my android application.I did not want to send this as an attachment.I want to show this in email body.Is it possible to by using **JavaMail api**?.Can i send an email like gmail application using javamail?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sending Emails in Android is very easy using the `Intent` mechanism, there is no reason to do this in a bad way.

Try reading [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-email-in-android/) and a bit of the Android documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, when you want to do something other than your app's primary focus, you normally use an `Intent` and ask for another application to do it. An application handling this intent is typically focussed on completing this objective. For ex: if you want to make a call, you normally hand it over to the dialler app, or if you want to send an email, you let the GMail, or other email app take care of it.

Easiest and recommended way to accomplish this is to fire an Intent.

Following code snippet should do the work for you.

```
Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); // says we want to SEND something
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"to.email@server.com"});
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "email subject");
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message content. Html should go here.");

// Some versions of android, doesn't recognize your intention is to send an email, 
// even though you specify the EXTRA_EMAIL and they show all sorts of apps as 
// options. Specifying the rfc type fixes this on most devices.

mailIntent.setType("message/rfc822"); 

// now we fire the intent

startActivity(mailntent);
```

Note that GMail app and default exchange app on android may show your html as text. In my experience, if you open the sent document in MS Outlook or similar application, it will recognize that the mail is in HTML.

Hope this helps.